# Display a custom field in node.tpl

Tags: drupal

I can't seem to figure out how to display (echo) a custom field I added to user profiles(via people > account settings > manage fields). 
I added a text field called team (field_team). I then clicked manage display and displayed it. It then shows up under there profile page. Great! 
However, now I will like to also display that on the frontpage and in the node view as well. How, or where do I do that?

**EDIT**: I ended up finding this article and this works. http://drupal.org/node/1194506

Code used:

```
<?php
  $node_author = user_load($node->uid);
  print ($node_author->roles[3]);
  print ($node_author->field_biography['und'][0]['value']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  must enable devel module to try this:

```
global $user;
dpm($user);
```

Hope that helps revealing the new field.